# How to shuffle the the element choosen by user input?

Tags: python

I have two array

```
arr_1 = [2, 4, 6, 32] 
arr_2 = [56, 45, 12, 65]
```

I am tying to give user_input from 'arr_1 list'

e.g. if I choose to give user_input '32' from 'arr_1 list', it should shuffle '32' to any position in 'arr_1 list' and along with '32' the element from 'arr_2  list' which is in same position that is '65' should also be shuffle. I tried many ways, but it shuffles all elements from a list using random.shuffle.

Comment: So you want to pick a number from `arr_1` (a `list`) and insert it at a random position inside `arr_2` (also a `list`). Is that correct? What have you tried so far?

Comment: what you are trying to achieving is not called shuffling.

Comment: @norok2, No I want to pick any number from arr_1(a list) and it shoud randomly move to any index position in arr_1. If I pick 4 from arr_1 then the number from arr_2 in same index position which is 45 should move to same index position in arr_2 list as that of 4 moved in arr_1.

Comment: You should update your example to show some kind of result you expect, and ideally some piece of code you tried so far

Comment: Where should it move, any exact place?

Comment: @Jen You should have given an example result of the two arrays for e.g picking `32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import randint

def shuffle_them(arr_1, arr_2, element_to_remove):
    # get the index where to be removed element is
    index_to_remove = arr_1.index(element_to_remove)

    # remove that element
    arr_1.remove(element_to_remove)
    
    # randomly generate the new index
    new_index = randint(0, len(arr_1))

    # insert the removed element into that position in array 1
    arr_1.insert(new_index, element_to_remove)

    # also change the position of elements in array 2 accordingly
    arr_2[new_index], arr_2[index_to_remove] = arr_2[index_to_remove], arr_2[new_index]
```

We find the index of element that user wants moving. Then we remove it. Then we generate a new index for it and insert it there. Lastly we use the original index and new index to exchange the values in the second array.

usage

```
# before
arr_1 = [2, 4, 6, 32]
arr_2 = [56, 45, 12, 65]

# shuffiling
shuffle_them(arr_1, arr_2, element_to_remove=32)

# after (32 and 65 places changed in same way)
> arr_1
[2, 32, 4, 6]

> arr_2
[56, 65, 12, 45]
```

another round

```
# before
arr_1 = [2, 4, 6, 32]
arr_2 = [56, 45, 12, 65]

# shuffiling
shuffle_them(arr_1, arr_2, element_to_remove=6)

# after (6 and 12 places changed in same way)
> arr_1
[2, 4, 32, 6]

> arr_2
[56, 45, 65, 12]
```

note: function directly mutates the mutable `arr_1` and `arr_2`. It doesn't return new lists.